# Angular mat-select not working in safari browser

Tags: angular, user-interface, browser, safari

Angular 6 mat-select option behavior not working for the whole application.

```
 <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" fxShow="true" fxHide="false" *ngIf="showbuyer">
   <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" class="removeselect">
     <mat-select placeholder="Buyer" floatLabel="never" (selectionChange)="buyerChange()" [(ngModel)]="buyerK">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let buyer of buyers;" [value]="buyer?.userKey">{{buyer?.userName}}</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

Comment: a stackblitz will help see what you're trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I removed override select CSS, now it is working  
if we want to apply any CSS class to <mat-select> we should use

 disableOptionCentering="" panelClass="custompanel" to <mat-select>

       <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <mat-select disableOptionCentering="" panelClass="custompanel" [(ngModel)]="typeAuction">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let auction of Typeauctions; " [value]="auction">{{auction}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

  For CSS

.custompanel{
             margin-top:64px;
            }
```